# Animating social icons in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am new to jQuery and I wanted to create an animation that when a user hovers over a social icon, the social icon the mouse is over, bounces up.

The problem is that while it kind of works as intended, its not the icon going up where the mouse is over, but all other icons move.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.social-icons img').hover(function () {
    // on mouse over, move up   
    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginBottom: '7px'
    }, 200);
},
// on mouse out, move back to original position
function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        marginBottom: '0px'
    }, 200);
});
});
```

Please check out my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/marvinjobs/4pcJ8/7/

The other problem I have is that I included the code on my index.html page and while it loads on www.marvinjobs.com/index.html , it does not work when simply opening www.marvinjobs.com

I hope someone can help me with these two problems!

Comment: it's best to do it with CSS transitions. Much easier.

Comment: @vsync I think he's using jquery for IE support I guess !

Comment: yes, i wanted it to be cross-browser compatible. furthermore, i am learning jquery right now, so I also just wanna test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, update the scripts like that...

See DEMO on jsfiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/4pcJ8/8/

For Q2 : have you included the jquery library properly?

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.social-icons img').hover(function() {
  // on mouse over, move up     
      $(this).stop().animate({ 'marginTop':'-10px', 'padding-bottom':'10px' },200);
  },
  // on mouse out, move back to original position
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ 'marginTop':'0px', 'padding-bottom':'0px' }, 200);
  });
});
```

Comment: that works! thanks a lot! i did not take into consideration that padding and margin both have to be included. thanks a lot. and I did include jquery properly, for some weird reasons, problem number 2 has solved itself and is working now also without /index.html

Comment: I've build floating social icons with animation effect with the above jquery code, its working fine but not in rtl mode. please check, here is the url http://jsfiddle.net/53a079cc/